# Why does this Translation of Curl into Python requests not produce the same response?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I try to translate the following Curl command into a call to `requests.request()`. The Curl command produces a 302 Response (as intended) and the requests call a 200 Response with different header items. But I fail to discern what's different:

**Curl**

```
curl -i 'https://some.domain.com/index/authorize?oa_token=123abc&locale=en_US' 
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' 
-H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' 
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' 
-H 'Referer: http://cool.domain.com/' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'
```

**requests**

```
req = requests.request("GET",
    "https://some.domain.com/index/authorize?oa_token={token}&locale=en_US".format(token="123abc"),
    headers={
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
        "Accept-Language": "de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": 1,
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Referer": "http://cool.domain.com/",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    }
)
```

**Any ideas what might be wrong?**

---

```
> requests.__version__
2.2.1

> sys.version
'2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your `request.request(...)` add the following switch `allow_redirects=False` to stop the redirection and you'll get `302` status.

Just for an info, you can also get the `200` code from your `curl` if you add `-L` switch. It means follow the location.